# Matlab: Magnetic fields calculated with biot-savarts-law

Tags: matlab, optimization, physics

This is the code for the computation of magnetic fields using the biot-savart-law. I hope to get some tipps for the optimization of this code. Regrettably I use german language :( I never will do this again. :)

```
tic
clear all; clc; clf
skalierungsfaktor = 10^-6; % vom m-Bereich zum mm-Bereich wg. T = Vs / m^2
I = 1; % in A
konstante = 10^-10; % mu0 / (4 pi) in Vs / (A mm) % Faktor 10^3 kleiner wg. mm statt m
matrix = 30;
B = zeros(200,200,200,5);
zaehler = 0; % für Zeitmessung
xmax = matrix;
ymax = matrix;
zmax = 1;
radius = 9; % Spulenradius in mm
genauigkeit = 5; % 1 = 6.28 Elemente pro Kreis; 2 = 12.56 Elemente pro Kreis; 4 bis 5 scheint gut zu sein
windungen = 10;
leiterelemente = ceil(2 * 3.14152 * genauigkeit * windungen) % 2 * Pi * genauigkeit für eine Umrundung
leiter = repmat(leiterelemente+1,3);
windungen = leiterelemente / genauigkeit / 2 / 3.1415927;
spulenlaenge = 20; % Spulenlaenge in mm
steigung = spulenlaenge / windungen
for i = 1:leiterelemente+1;
    leiter(i,1) = i * steigung / (genauigkeit * 2 * 3.1415927) + matrix/2 - spulenlaenge/2;  % x-Ausrichtung
    leiter(i,2) = radius * cos(i/genauigkeit) + matrix/2;  % y-Ausrichtung
    leiter(i,3) = radius * sin(i/genauigkeit);   % z-Ausrichtung
end
for x = 1:xmax
zaehler = zaehler + 1; % für Zeitmessung
hhh = waitbar(0,num2str(zaehler*100/matrix)); % Wartebalken
waitbar(zaehler/matrix) % Wartebalken
for y = 1:ymax % wenn streamslice nicht genutzt wird, nur einen y-Wert berechnen
    for z = 1:zmax
        for i = 1:leiterelemente
            dl(1) = leiter(i+1,1)-leiter(i,1);
            dl(2) = leiter(i+1,2)-leiter(i,2);
            dl(3) = leiter(i+1,3)-leiter(i,3);
            vecs = [(leiter(i,1)+leiter(i+1,1))/2, ...
                (leiter(i,2)+leiter(i+1,2))/2, ...
                (leiter(i,3)+leiter(i+1,3))/2];
            vecr = [x y z];
            vecrminusvecs = vecr - vecs;
            einheitsvecr = vecrminusvecs./norm(vecrminusvecs); % ok
            r = sqrt(vecrminusvecs(1).^2 + vecrminusvecs(2).^2 + vecrminusvecs(3).^2); % ok
            vektorprodukt = [dl(2).*einheitsvecr(3) - dl(3).*einheitsvecr(2), ...
                dl(3).*einheitsvecr(1) - dl(1).*einheitsvecr(3), ...
                dl(1).*einheitsvecr(2) - dl(2).*einheitsvecr(1)];
            dB = konstante * I * vektorprodukt / (r.^2);
            dB = dB / skalierungsfaktor; % nur hier wird der Wert verändert bzw. skaliert
            B(x,y,z,1) = B(x,y,z,1) + dB(1);
            B(x,y,z,2) = B(x,y,z,2) + dB(2);
            B(x,y,z,3) = B(x,y,z,3) + dB(3);
            B(x,y,z,4) = B(x,y,z,4) + sqrt(dB(1).^2 + dB(2).^2 + dB(3).^2);
        end;
    end;
end;
close(hhh) 
end;
toc
n = 1:leiterelemente;
Lx = leiter(n,1);
Ly = leiter(n,2);
Lz = leiter(n,3);
%subplot(2,1,2), 
line(Lx,Ly,Lz,'Color','k','LineWidth',2); 
hold on
view(15,30);            % view(0,0) = Blickwinkel, 2D-Perspektive
grid on                 % Gitter anzeigen
xlim([0 matrix])
ylim([0 matrix])
zlim([0 5])
xlabel('x-Achse');
ylabel('y-Achse');
zlabel('z-Achse');
daspect([1 1 1])
[X,Y]=meshgrid(1:matrix);
U=(B(1:matrix,1:matrix,z,1))'; 
V=(B(1:matrix,1:matrix,z,2))';
streamslice(X,Y,U,V) % quiver, streamslice
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

not necessarily speed optimization, but some notes:

- use `pi`, not 3.14159 or 3.1415927
- you can generally vectorize your loops:

nonvectorized:

```
for i = 1:leiterelemente+1;
    leiter(i,1) = i * steigung / (genauigkeit * 2 * 3.1415297) + matrix/2 - spulenlaenge/2;  % x-Ausrichtung
    leiter(i,2) = radius * cos(i/genauigkeit) + matrix/2;  % y-Ausrichtung
    leiter(i,3) = radius * sin(i/genauigkeit);   % z-Ausrichtung
end
```

vectorized:

```
ii = 1:leiterelemente+1;
leiter(ii,1) = ii * steigung / (genauigkeit * 2 * 3.1415297) + matrix/2 - spulenlaenge/2;  % x-Ausrichtung
leiter(ii,2) = radius * cos(ii/genauigkeit) + matrix/2;  % y-Ausrichtung
leiter(ii,3) = radius * sin(ii/genauigkeit);   % z-Ausrichtung
```

Most matlab functions will take vectors/matrices as arguments, including `cos()`, `sin()`, `exp()`, `log()`, etc.

For low numbers of elements (say < a few hundred) it may not be worth the effort to vectorize.

Vector magnitude: instead of `sqrt(dB(1).^2 + dB(2).^2 + dB(3).^2)` use `norm(dB)` (note that norm does NOT operate on a matrix in a row-wise fashion but rather on the whole) though that won't save much

```
        B(x,y,z,1) = B(x,y,z,1) + dB(1);
        B(x,y,z,2) = B(x,y,z,2) + dB(2);
        B(x,y,z,3) = B(x,y,z,3) + dB(3);
```

consider changing to

B(x,y,z,1:3) = B(x,y,z,1:3) + dB(1:3);

Why are you calculating r using a square root when you are just squaring it later?

```
r = sqrt(vecrminusvecs(1).^2 + vecrminusvecs(2).^2 + vecrminusvecs(3).^2);
```

Change to

```
r2 = sum(vecrminusvecs.^2);
```

and use `r2` in place of `r.^2`

My guess is you can probably simplify the calculations from "vecrminusvecs = ..." to "db = konstante..." by using some vector algebra; you're doing some rescaling that doesn't quite seem like it's necessary, or at least could be optimized for speed.

**edit**: I am now suspicious of "norm"; `sqrt(sum(x.^2,2))` operates on each row and is probably faster than `norm()` but you should measure it if you want to use the fastest approach.

Comment: Thanks, but much more time is needed in the following for-loops.

Comment: hmm, I wonder if "norm" is slow because of its flexibility. If you need to optimize, try making changes one by one and see which ones work.

Answer (score 2):

What do you want to optimize? Speed? The first tip of optimization:

**Measure it.**

So, first measure where you spend most of the time (probably in some loop). Put timers around so that you get a good feel of it. Then see if you could do something about it. You can't optimize as long as you don't know what you need to optimize.

That said, the general rule with Matlab is to try to avoid loops (especially nested ones) at all costs and instead figure out how to present your computations as matrix operations. They are fast and optimized.

Comment: Yes the speed!
I already measured it and also improved some parts. But there is more potential to improve this I think.

Comment: Did you use the Matlab profiler too ?  If not, do so immediately.  It will probably save some of your time compared to instrumenting the program with tic and toc.

Comment: MATLAB profiler is a great help. The first year I was using MATLAB, I was always surprised at what operations took up the majority of the time when executing a script. There's usually a simple work-around for problem areas, such as vectorization, or omitting repetitive plot commands.

Answer (score 1):

I ran this code in the MATLAB profiler, and a couple of things stand out:

1. You are creating and destroying the waitbar each time around the x = 1:xmax loop - you should keep the waitbar open the whole time. This was taking a fair amount of time on my machine.
2. You really do need to vectorize at least the three inner loops. For example, your calculation of "dl" could be replaced by a single call to (something like - untested) `dl = diff( leiter, 1, 1 )`. Likewise, `vecs = (leiter(1:N-1,:) + leiter(2:N,:))/2`. The remaining expressions in that loop need a bit more work to tease apart.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a 20ppm error, but pi ~= 3.1415927 != 3.1415297.  (you have a typo which switched the 2 and the 9).  Another reason besides convenience to use the built-in constant.